# Users strange behaviour

Tags: support, answers, users, questions

I noticed something about [this user](https://askubuntu.com/users/25388/masi), almost all questions they ask are answered for them in comments or by other users and they take this information and create there own answers with it and accept it, just look at there question history.

Here is an example,[To sync notes of S Memo to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/648621/to-sync-notes-of-s-memo-to-ubuntu/789794#789794) , a question that was answered, not accepted and then the user put the information from the answer, in to another answer, made it a wiki, then accepted it.

I don't know why they are doing this but something seems very wrong here, is it just me or is this very strange behavior?

I think a mod should take a look at this, while self answers are encouraged, it should not be at the expense of other users contributions.

Answer (score 5):

It is a correct behaviour to convert a comment to an answer and mark it as wiki if the answerer did not write an answer themselves.

Nothing is wrong. I do it too.

Comment: True of course. If an existing answer is *almost* the answer you were looking for, it shows more courtesy however to suggest (or make) a small edit and accept the existing answer imo. It shows recognition of the effort someone took to answer your question.

Comment: I understand summarizing comments in to an answer but it is the frequency of that has my interest. I agree, more users should take comments and convert them to answers but it seems to be every question they ask, even some with good answers already.

Comment: @MarkKirby And what is you suggestion? The user did not do anything seriously wrong.

Comment: I did not say they did, the fact they converted it to wiki shows they are not doing it for the rep. i don't have a suggestion, that is why I asked here for opinions of others, it seems strange but not malicious. You don't think the frequency of this is unusual?

Comment: It may be unusual, but nothing criminal that is worth mods attention.

Comment: Converting comments to answers makes a lot of sense. Duplicating existing answers in new answers is a bit weird... IMHO. Isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the user just wants to help others by summarizing the comments as answer. Also as the user is making them wiki I seriously see no personal gains on the users part.